# accessing pixel image c++

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

```
    cv::Mat depth_clean(cv_depthptr->image.rows, cv_depthptr->image.cols, CV_32FC1);
    cv::Mat img(cv_depthptr->image.rows, cv_depthptr->image.cols, CV_8UC1);
    for(int i = 0; i < cv_depthptr->image.rows; i++)
    {
        float* Di = cv_depthptr->image.ptr<float>(i);
        float* Ii = depth_clean.ptr<float>(i);
        char* Ivi = img.ptr<char>(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < cv_depthptr->image.cols; j++)
            {   
               if(Di[j] > 0.0f){                        
                Ii[j] = Di[j];
                Ivi[j] = (char) (255*((Di[j])/(5.5))); // some suitable values..
               }
                else{
                Ii[j] = 0.0f;
                Ivi[j] = 0;
                }
            }   
    }
```

Can anyone explain to me using that program how the accessing to the pixel has been done ? using pointer and the two loops and what the different between cv_depthptr->image.ptr(i) and Di[j] ?

Thank you so much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173933/accessing-pixel-image-c++/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2014-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is your use case?

The `image.ptr<float>(i)` gives you a pointer to the first element (element at position zero) in the i'th row.

The call `Di[j]` gives you a read/write reference to the element j positions "behind" where Di  is pointing.

Basically this is how element access in OpenCV could be done with pointers. However, OpenCV2 provides you more convienient way to access your elements such as the `cv::Mat::at<T>()` method (slow but convenient if you just need to modifiy a couple of pixels) or the `cv::MatIterator<T>` (the proper way to iterate all elements of your matrix)...

See OpenCV Doc:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat%3A%3Aptr#template%3Ctypename%20_Tp%3E%20_Tp*%20Mat::ptr%28int%20i0%29

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat%3A%3Aat#template%3Ctypename%20T%3E%20T&%20Mat::at%28int%20i%29%20const

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=matiterator#template%3Ctypename%20_Tp%3E%20MatIterator_%3C_Tp%3E%20Mat::begin%28%29

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-06-19**:
OK I don't care about the use of the program I want to understand how the stuffs work because I just start learning Opencv.
Thank you so much

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-06-19**:
You should ask this question here:

> http://answers.opencv.org/questions/

or here

> http://stackoverflow.com

or check the documentation of OpenCV as suggested Wolf.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-06-19**:
Well, it slightly depends on your use case whether it is suitable to use pointers, Mat::at or MatIterators to access the pixels.... The example you gave just requests a pointer to the 1. element of each row and then applies simple pointer arithmetic to get the following elements of the row...